# Is it not good to provide links to the answers?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

I am just one month old to Stack Overflow. I just want to know if it is not good to provide links that will relate or answers to the questions. Because, I got some comment (to the answers that provide with extra links) indicating that redirection to other site is not a good way of answering. Is providing related link to the question can be treated as bad way of answering?